# Pass argument to leiningen readable by project.clj

Tags: clojure, command-line-arguments, argument-passing, leiningen

I have a `project.clj` file that I want to use differently depending on an argument passed in when called by leiningen.  Here is my hypothetical sample project

```
(defproject simple "0.0.1"
  :source-paths [(get-argument "source.path")])
```

(In this case `get-argument` would simply call `System/getProperty`). I would use this file like this,

```
lein2 compile -Dsource.path=path/to/location
```

The problem is two-fold,

- I don't know how to pass an argument to leiningen.  It doesn't accept the `-Dkey=value` syntax.  I couldn't find anything in documentation about passing optional/extra arguments.  Am I missing something obvious?
- The subforms inside `defproject` seem to be handled a special way.  I couldn't find an easy way to put code into it.

I have found some approaches

- https://github.com/weavejester/environ looks promising, but it seems to work only in proper clojure code, not inside project.clj
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/leiningen/t8G6Et1_j8w -- this is a workaround that may solve half of the problem
- [What is an elegant way to set up a leiningen project that requires different dependencies based on the build platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688336/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-set-up-a-leiningen-project-that-requires-different-dep) gives some idea how to eval code in project.clj
- https://github.com/sattvik/leinjacker promises to do some dirty tricks, but I couldn't make it work in my environment

(What I actually want to use it for is that I have a clojurescript project with different artifacts.  While it's possible to configure different builds for it, they all share the same crossovers.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach that is convenient on unix-like platforms is to use an environment variable, combined with lein's willingness to evaluate expressions marked with a tilde in `project.clj` files.  So for your example, you could provide a `project.clj` like:

```
(defproject simple "0.0.1"
  :source-paths [~(System/getenv "MY_SRC_PATH")]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.0"]])
```

...then set the environment variable when launching lein like this:

```
MY_SRC_PATH="s2" lein compile
```

I don't know how well this approach would work on Windows.